# StartupUri VisualStudio 2010 not working

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I just created a new WPF project, but I decided to make a different organization of the folders, to make them look like this:

[image]

So I want all my interfaces to be on `src` folder. But when I press F5 and try to run it, the debugger says it can't find `MainWindow.xaml`. The xaml look like this:

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="MyNamespace.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

Apparently they share the same namespace, but it's not finding the `MainWindow.xaml`... Any idea why?

**App.xaml.cs**

```
namespace MyNamespace.src
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MainWindow` is in the the `"src"` folder.

The `StartupUri` is relative to the structure of your project.
So `StartupUri = "src\MainWindow.xaml"` should work.

Comment: Yes, I want it to be there. But it doesn't find it... Can you see something I can't??

Answer (score 1):

Change the startupuri to "src/MainWindow.xaml", this works for me with an empty project.

Also, in App.xaml.cs, you have `namespace MyNamespace.src`, this may not be what you intended (doesn't match the others). Sometimes VS automatically appends to the end of your namespaces when you create subfolders.